# GetCustomAttribute always returns null

Tags: reflection

I have an attribute class

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class WizardAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool AddGuid { get; set; }

    public WizardAttribute()
    {
    }

}
```

I'm trying to get this attribute via reflection like this

```
                    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "bin\\some.dll");
                Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
                foreach (Type tt in types)
                {
                    if (tt.Name == "Somecontroller")
                    {
                        WizardAttribute attribute = (WizardAttribute)(tt.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(WizardAttribute)));
                    }
                }
```

and attributes always null

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it I change the loading assembly to

```
                    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "bin\\SwiftNess.Portal.dll");
```